# What is the difference between jsp and ftl

Tags: jsp, freemarker

I have seen jsp and ftl files. ftl are dynamically constructed and jsp's are also dynamically constructed. what is the big difference and which one is better to use.

Comment: Related threads - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559727/jsp-vs-freemarker and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610062/jsp-vs-velocity-what-is-better

Answer (score 3):

- JSP files are *JavaServer Pages*. See [the related Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages).
- FTL files are typically *FreeMarker Templates*. See [the related Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeMarker) and [the FreeMarker website](http://freemarker.org).

Both are indeed templates that are processed by the respective technology to generate textual contents, often HTML. However, there are several important differences between both technologies.